# Why does the validation on my compareTo method make the output wrong?

Tags: java, compareto

For homework one of my methods has to compare the user's first name and last name, and output which comes first alphabetically. I am able to write the code and make everything lowercase and use the `compareTo` to get an integer, and it works just fine. But when I purposely input a number, the validation somehow makes the output always go to "they both equal each other" when they do not equal each other.

```
public static void alpha() {
    //takes two names, makes them lowercase, and sorts them using uniCode
    System.out.println("Please input the first name you want me to organize.");
    String firstC = isValidString();
    String fir = firstC.toLowerCase();
    
    System.out.println("Please input the second name you want me to organize.");
    String secondC = isValidString();
    String sec = secondC.toLowerCase();
    
    int uniOut = fir.compareTo(sec);
    if (uniOut > 0) {
        System.out.printf("%s is first alphabetically", secondC);
    } else if (uniOut < 0) {
        System.out.printf("%s is first alphabetically", firstC);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Those names are the same.");
    }
}

public static String isValidString() {
    //validates input as a string and has the user continue to input until it is a string
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (in.hasNextDouble()) {
        double input = in.nextDouble();
        System.out.printf("%f is not a valid input, please try again.\n", input);
    }
    String s = in.nextLine();
    return s;
}
```

The `isValidString()` is another method I have that works perfectly for the other methods in this class, so I don't think that is the problem.

I have tried changing the  `}else{`  to an  `}else if{`  to specify that both strings equal each other and I had a 'buffer' else, and the output still said that the strings were equal.

I tried to input one string correctly the first time, and try the validation on the other (in both ways), but that also gave a weird output, where it would say " is first alphabetically". I do not know why the validation is making the variables act weird, but I cannot think of a way to fix this.

Comment: I would suggest printing the values of `fir` and `sec`, to see if they are actually the same string somehow. `String.compareTo` is a built-in method, and definitely works.

Comment: The problem is in `isValidString()`. The method returns `""`. Which is a valid string. And empty. And since you call it twice, `fir` does in fact equal `sec`. That's my **guess** anyway. If I'm wrong, post that method and tell us what input you are using. So we can actually reproduce the problem. Instead of guessing. Thank you.

Comment: Please read: [How to debug small programs (`https://ericlippert.com/`)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: I see that you have the "informed" badge so I assume that you read [ask] and saw the part about posting a [mcve]. Unfortunately, your question only contains part of your code where you think the problem is. In order for me to help you debug your code, I need you to post code that reproduces your problem. I suggest that you [edit] your question and post a reproducible example.

Comment: “the isValidString() is another method I have that works perfectly for other methods in this class, so I don't think that is the problem” try replacing the calls to `isValidString` with hardcoded string literals and see if the problem still happens. If not, then the problem is in `isValidString`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13102066/29470

Comment: Refer to this SO question (and answers): [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next() or nextFoo()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo) After calling method [nextDouble](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#nextDouble()) and before calling method `nextLine`, you need an extra call to method `nextLine`. The linked question will explain why.

Answer (score -6):

> *"... compare the user's first name and last name, and output which comes first alphabetically. I am able to write the code and make everything lowercase and use the .compareTo to get an integer ..."*

Use the *[compareToIgnoreCase](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#compareToIgnoreCase(java.lang.String))* instead.

```java
String a = "789", b = "123";
int i = Integer.compare(a.compareToIgnoreCase(b), 0);
String s = a + switch (i) {
    case -1 -> '<';
    case 0 -> '=';
    default -> '>';
} + b;
```

Output

```
abc<xyz
```

Comment: Probably a good idea to indicate to a beginning Java student that the code in your answer uses [switch expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/language/pattern-matching-switch-expressions-and-statements.html#GUID-E69EEA63-E204-41B4-AA7F-D58B26A3B232) as I doubt that he has learned them yet.

Comment: A switch **expression** is not exactly the same as a `switch` statement - as far as syntax is concerned.

Comment: @Abra, I imagine a _Java_ student knows what a _switch statement_ is, lol.